# Java, value changed in main via methods, how to pass this value correctly to other classes

Tags: java, class

I have a problem, tried to make it work several ways, but cant do it right.
It has to be this class structure like in examples.
About the problem. I am calling a method in main class

```
public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Moving moving = new Moving();
        moving.forward();
        moving.forward();
        System.out.println(moving.move.y); //prints 10;
        moving.status(); //prints 0; I need it to print 10 too;

    }
}
```

My instance in Main is Moving class object :

```
public class Moving {
    Move move = new Move();
    Status status = new Status();

    public void forward() {
        this.move.moving(5);

    }

    public void backwards() {
        this.move.moving((-5));

    }

    public void status() {
        status.getStatus();

    }

}
```

Which passes parameters to class Move:

```
public class Move {

    int y;
    String  forward =   "forward";
    String  back =  "back";

    public void moving( int howMuch) {
        y+=howMuch;

    }public int getY() {
    return this.y;


}

}
```

And last class has to print information (int y value), which are changing when calling forward() or backwards methods in Main.

```
public class Status {
    Move move = new Move();
    int y;

    public void setStatus(Move move) {
        this.y = move.getY();
    }

    public void getStatus() {
        System.out.println(this.y);

    }
}
```

And here Im struggling to make it work. Once I somehow succeded when I changed int y to static int y; , but with non static, I cant make it work.

Comment: So you have one class that instantiates two classes, both holding the information of y position? I'm sorry to say it, but this seems like extremely bad design, and it's actually pretty hard to give a good answer because I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Its a part of bigger thing, and I need those classes. And its for learning purposes to learn how to operate with multiple, not one or few classes. I need to print variable int y in main method from Status class, which has to take value from Move class.

Comment: You should not hold `y` in Status. Pass a `Move` object to the `Status` consturctor and hold a reference to that instead of creating another Move in Status. The `getStatus` method should use `move.y`.

Comment: could you give me a little example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`moving.status()` is printing 0 because you're not setting/updating the value of `y` attribute in the Status class. You have multiple options to accomplish this:

**Change your main method:**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Moving moving = new Moving();
        moving.forward();
        moving.forward();
        System.out.println(moving.move.y); //prints 10;
        moving.status.setStatus(moving.move);
        moving.status(); //prints 0; I need it to print 10 too;
 }
```

**OR 
Change your status() method in Moving class:**

```
public void status() {
    status.setStatus(move);
    status.getStatus();
}
```

**OR Change the structure of your Status class:**

```
public class Status {
    Move move;

    public Status(Move move) {
        this.move = move;
    }

    public void getStatus() {
        System.out.println(move.y);
    }
}
```

Personally, I would choose the last option, as @DodgyCodeException suggested. The reason for this choice is the fact that status should not hold an attribute that does not identify with the class purpose. For instance, imagine that you have a Car class and a Garage class. It wouldn't make much sense to put `carColor` as an attribute of Garage, since it is a characteristic for Car. Garage should hold attributes such as `int numberOfCars` or `Car[] cars` instead.

If you also choose the last option, don't forget to replace `Status status = new Status();` to `Status status = new Status(move);` in your Moving class.